# Left join returns empty resultset

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT branch_name, workerID, COUNT(*) 
FROM company_branch 
LEFT JOIN workers ON workers.branchID = company_branch.branchID 
WHERE companyID=? 
GROUP BY workers.branchID
```

I have a databases of companies, company branches and workers. Each company has branches and each branch has workers.

> **Tree:** Company > Company branch > workers

Now what i want is to get a list of all branches and worker count for every branch.

My query works, but not when 0 workers work for the branch. I want list of all company branches even thought there arent any workers.

Comment: What table is companyID coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the data your *have* / is guaranteed, not by some data in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
GROUP BY company_branch.branchID
```

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping on `workers.branchID`. If a branch has no workers, then that field will actually be null. You should be grouping on `company_branch.brandID` instead. Since that's on the left-side of the join, it will always be available, regardless of how many (or few) workers are actually attached to that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify what Mark B and Wrikken have written:

What happens when you use a `GROUP BY` on a field that is potentially null is you're not listing zero records, but you're lumping together all `company_branch` records with no (`NULL`) workers  - which is what your `COUNT(*)` value will indicate.

Here is an example of what's happening in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fa23/2/0

There you have two branches ('Branch 2.1' and 'Branch 2.2') and neither have workers. So your `COUNT(*)` is 2, but only the first `company_branch` record is showing, and it's all in a single record.

The solution is as Mark B and Wrikken have stated - change your `GROUP BY` to use `company_branch.branchID`.